# How to return matches and non matches when comparing two ranges/arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to return a count of the total number of matching and non-matching entries in a set of two ranges.

I'm trying to avoid looping over the array twice like this:

```
#expected output:
#inside: 421 | outside: 55

constant_range = 240..960
sample_range   = 540..1015
sample_range_a = sample_range.to_a

def generate_range
  inside = sample_range_a.select { |val| constant_range.include?(val) }.count
  outside = sample_range_a.select { |val| !constant_range.include?(val) }.count
end

# I was thinking of a counter, but thought that would be even more ineffective
def generate_range
  a = 0
  b = 0
  sample_range_a.select { |val| constant_range.include?(val) ? a++ : b++ }
end
```

Comment: No need to prefix your title with "Ruby - "; that's what tags are for.

Comment: Use the built-in `+` and `-`? Or a Set?

Comment: If it's just two ranges, compare their starts and ends. You don't need to iterate them at all

Comment: I'm avoiding using `+` / `-` in the case where the sample range is less than the constant range

Comment: You're using post-increment `++`, but Ruby doesn't support that. Instead use `+= 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constant_range = (240..960).to_a

sample_range   = (540..1015).to_a

inside_count = (sample_range & constant_range).count #inside: 421

outside_count = sample_range.count - inside_count #outside: 55
```

Comment: It's painfully inefficient to convert the ranges to arrays.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is entirely your case, but if they're always number ranges with an interval of 1 and not any arbitrary array, the solution can be optimized to O(1), unlike the other methods using `to_a` that are at least O(n). In other words, if you have a BIG range, those array solutions would choke badly.

Assuming that you'll always use an ascending range of numbers with interval of 1, it means you can count them just by using `size` (`count` would be our enemy in this situation).

With that said, using simple math you can first check if the ranges may intersect, if not, just return 0. Otherwise, you can finally calculate the new range interval and get its size.

```
def range_intersection_count(x, y)
  return 0 if x.last < y.first || y.last < x.first
  ([x.begin, y.begin].max..[x.max, y.max].min).size
end
```

This will count the number of elements that intersect in two ranges in O(1). You can test this code with something like

```
range_intersection_count(5000000..10000000000, 3000..1000000000000)
```

and then try the same input with the other methods and watch your program hang.

The final solution would look something like this:

```
constant_range = (240..960)
sample_range   = (540..1015)

inside_count   = range_intersection_count(constant_range, sample_range) # = 421
outside_count  = sample_range.size - inside_count                       # = 55
```

Comment: I would simplify `sample_range.last - sample_range.first + 1` to `sample_range.size`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-` (difference) in Ruby:

```rb
constant_range = (240..960).to_a
sample_range   = (540..1015).to_a

puts (sample_range - constant_range).count # 55
```

Comment: These cases don't cover the possibility when the sample range is < the start of the constant_range, i.e. `sample_range   = (1..180).to_a`

Comment: i mean use logic like `-  & |`  i example for one

Comment: It's painfully inefficient to convert the ranges to arrays.